# Strategy to ensure educated workers in Tropico 3?

Tags: tropico-3

In Tropico 3 its important to have a workforce of high school and sometime college educated workers.  How can I build up my educated workforce, and ensure that I have a steady stream of new ones to man my factories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a high school as soon as it's needed, but not sooner.

It usually makes  economical sense to hire  up to four educated workers to start your industry, but after that, you must get the high school and the university.

And make sure the educated jobs are payed well, that is, 40% over the average uneducated workers. Else people won't bother about studying.

Comment: I might add the edict that increases learning rate.  I find it's well worth the cost on my islands.